# Proving The relationship between The Gamma Distribution and The Poisson Process.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

How would one prove the relationship between The Gamma Distribution and the Poisson Process. Namely, if X~Gamma($\alpha,\theta)$ and $\alpha\geq1$ is an integer, then $Pr[X>x]$ for the Gamma Distribution would be $\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha-1}$$\frac{(x/\theta)^k e^{-x/\theta}}{k!}$?

Comment: Please sort out the formatting and consider accepting answers to some of your previous questions.

Comment: Are you aware how to use latex? It is very easy to learn

Comment: Noooo it is free! When you post on this forum. Basically your mathematical expressions inside dollar signs would make it appear 'professional' as you say like $\cos(\pi) = -1

Comment: Add another dollar sign to the expression on my last comment gives you $\cos(\pi)=-1$

Comment: Previous problem? As in this one or another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume the arrival time between two arrivals of a Poisson process is exponential. This simply follows from the fact, sum of n independent exponential distributions with parameter x, is distributed as Gamma (n,x).

For this result, you can use the moment generating function method.

Comment: great answer! any chance you can present the derivation if you have time? thanks!